# Need help after setting my /etc folder to chmod 777

Tags: command-line, permissions, ssh, chmod

So I did the really dumb CARELESS action of running sudo chmod -R 777 ./ while in the etc folder.
I can’t ssh into my server or anything now.
I feel like an absolute idiot ofcourse because this could have been SOOOO easily avoided…

Is there any like script or command or anything like that that would go though all the folders and files and set them back to the default permissions.
Basically a script that has a large catalog of default system files and folders and their corasponding permissions, and can set them back to their original state.
Any suggestion would be appreciated since I was working on a live project

Comment: @Pilot6 Well in a way yes BUT I can’t even ssh into the server now, completely stuck out of it.

Comment: So there is no way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you need a physical (or VPS console) connect to the machine, 'cos you made runnable whole etc.
Probably you can try using shell-connect (eg. with mc), if you luck shell-connect can tolerate 777 permission on itself's configuration file.